# Import BitcoinCore's blockchain into bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinj

I'm a newbie in bitcoin. I've started programming some software using bitcoinj to make some transactions in bitcoin's testnet.
But there is a huge problem I faced with. I cannot normally download the blockchain with bitcoinj. The speed is so slow and what is more when I tried to save all the data into PostgreSql, the speed dropped down much more...

If I use BitcoinCore to download the blockchain, the speed is okay and it's about 1 day to download everything. What's pretty good for me. So, I'm here to ask if there is some way to import BitcoinCore's downloaded blockchain into bitcoinj ?

Comment: My impression was that `bitcoinj` is not a full node implementation but a library. You’d usually pair it with a full node to get local access to blockchain data.